# C++ constructor specialization using SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, sfinae, template-specialization

I have a templated struct whose member type depends on the specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    typedef T VT[4];
}

template<>
struct Base<float>
{
    typedef ___m128 VT;
} // And other similar specializations for int, uint etc...

template<typename T>
struct A
{
     typename A<T>::VT data;
}
```

I would like to specialize the copy constructor for pointer and non-pointer types:

```
// Non-pointer
A::A(const A & a) : data(a.data) { }

// Pointer
A::A(const A & a) { memcpy(data, a.data, sizeof(data)); }
```

I tried using a combination of `std::enable_if` and `std::is_pointer` but I cannot seem to make it work. Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430090/sfinae-away-a-copy-constructor, may be a duplicate.

Comment: @Matthieu I think I did (in the sense that I'm not sure whether I did that correctly or not) but the compiler gave me a redefined error on the constructor

Comment: Then perhaps share your trials so that we can figure out the issue with your constructor.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'll edit my question as soon as I get my hands on the computer. That link you posted talks about conditionally disabling the copy constructor, which is not what I want, but I'll give it a look to see if it applies to my case too