# Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor in a class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have written a class template and only want to make the copy constructor conditionally available. To do this, I want to apply some SFINAE trick and need to make the copy constructor templated.

Something like:

```
template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T> && /* conditions on U */> * = nullptr>
Foo(const Foo<U> &);
```

However, I run into issues because I have a normal move constructor defined and the compiler complains that it implicitly deleted the copy constructor because of my user-defined move constructor. It does not want to match the templated copy constructor I wrote.

I have the following example code that reproduces my problem:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo final
{
    Foo() = default;

    template <typename U = T>
    Foo(const Foo<U> &);

    Foo(Foo<T> &&);
};

int main()
{
    auto f1 = Foo<int>{};
    auto f2 = Foo<int>{f1};
}
```

And I get the following error when compiling with Clang 9.0.0 over on Godbolt:

```
<source>:15:15: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Foo<int>'
    auto f2 = Foo<int>{f1};
              ^       ~~~~
<source>:9:5: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'Foo<int>' has a user-declared move constructor
    Foo(Foo<T> &&)
    ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

The compile error describes only symptoms and not my actual mistake. I can usually deduce what I did wrong but in this case, because using SFINAE on constructors is quite new to me, I cannot figure out the root cause of the error.

Can anyone help me fix the code to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does describe your actual mistake:

```
<source>:9:5: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'Foo<int>' has a user-declared move constructor
Foo(Foo<T> &&)
```

Solution: add a copy constructor (signature: `Foo(const Foo<T>&)`) or remove the move constructor (i.e., allow the compiler to generate the copy constructor).

Note that `template <typename U = T> Foo(const Foo<U> &);` is not a copy constructor because it is templated. Copy constructors must not be templated.

Comment: Can you suggest any tricks I can apply to make the copy constructor only conditionally available?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430090/sfinae-away-a-copy-constructor

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! It makes it painfully clear my approach was a complete dead end... hopefully we can use the `requires` keyword soon for a more elegant solution to this problem.